# Was the motive behind this ever explained by the author of The Virgin Suicides?

Tags: character-analysis, the-virgin-suicides, jeffrey-eugenides

In the novel *[The Virgin Suicides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Virgin_Suicides)*, we find that every daughter of the Lisbon family has attempted to suicide and succeeded.

However, at the end of the novel, we don't find any motive behind all of this.

**Was the motive behind the suicides ever explained by the author?**

Because this was never explained in the novel, I am looking for an out-of-universe explanation.

Comment: Related: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3010/481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [interview](http://www.dazeddigital.com/artsandculture/article/16814/1/jeffrey-eugenides-virgin-suicides) with Jeffrey Eugenides by *Dazed Digital* (published 06 August 2013) includes this question and answer:

> **DD: In *The Virgin Suicides* you wrote, ‘Something sick at the heart of the country had infected the girls.’ Were you anchoring that in the
>   political situation of 1993?**
>
> **Jeffrey Eugenides:** I certainly was. I
>   grew up in Detroit in the 60s, which was haemorrhaging population.
>   There were race riots and a feeling of national decline which affected
>   my mood growing up. I assumed that it would affect the moods and
>   disposition of the Lisbon girls as well. I was living in Germany when
>   the book came out in the 90s, and they were calling America a
>   ‘hyper-power’ because of the resurgence of the economy during the
>   Clinton years. I thought, ‘The prediction I made in *The Virgin
>   Suicides* is not exactly right. I shouldn’t be too pessimistic in
>   life.’ And then there was the crash in 2008! Basically, I was right,
>   but I’m trying not to be too pessimistic. There’s still a lot of
>   potential for any generation in any country.

Comment: A quote from the author is a good start, but there's probably a lot more you could say using tools such as close reading.

Comment: I know that, @Hamlet, but I have not read the book in question (and am not sure that I want to). This quote is a drop better than some others, because there is a little bit of analysis (and analysis of the text, as well) included.

Comment: @Hamlet The OP specifically says "Was the motive behind the suicides ever explained by the author? [...] I am looking for an out-of-universe explanation." You might say that's a poor way to frame it, but I don't think this answer deserves to be downvoted for answering the question as stated.